# Failed to link osmesa correctly

Tags: opengl, mesa, off-screen

Mesa version = 12.0.1
Tried version before this as well.
At link time this error comes up: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libGL.so: undefined reference to _glapi_tls_Dispatch'`.

The script i am using to install mesa:

```
#!/bin/bash

make -j4 distclean # if in an existing build

autoreconf -fi

./configure \
    CXXFLAGS="-O2 -g -DDEFAULT_SOFTWARE_DEPTH_BITS=31" \
    CFLAGS="-O2 -g -DDEFAULT_SOFTWARE_DEPTH_BITS=31" \
    --disable-xvmc \
    --disable-glx \
    --disable-dri \
    --with-dri-drivers="" \
    --with-gallium-drivers="swrast" \
    --enable-texture-float \
    --enable-shared-glapi \
    --disable-egl \
    --with-egl-platforms="" \
    --enable-gallium-osmesa \
    --enable-llvm-shared-libs=yes \
    --enable-gallium-llvm=yes \
    --prefix=/home/ec2-user/new-mesa/mesaBuild/

make -j2
make -j4 install
```

After installation :

1. Added `prefix`(defined in script) to `/etc/ld.so.conf`' and ran `ldconfig`
2. Then in link command: `-Lprefix -lOSMesa`

What am i doing wrong?